# Error when show data to recycler view in fragment

Tags: java, android

I have an problem when show data in `fragment`. I send data from another `activity` to `fragment` and show it but it's show. Here is my code.
Function in `activity`:

```
    public void sendResultRoundtripDomestic(ArrayList<ItemSearch> listOutbound, ArrayList<ItemSearch> listInbound) {
    listItemOutbound = ListItem.createSearchOnewayDomesticResult(listOutbound);
    outboundFragment = new OutboundFragment(listItemOutbound, 0);
    listItemInbound = ListItem.createSearchOnewayDomesticResult(listInbound);
    inboundFragment = new InboundFragment(listItemInbound, 1);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

And here is my `fragment` I want to show

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outbound, container, false);
    rvResultOutbound = (RecyclerView) rv.findViewById(R.id.roundtrip_outbound);
    adapterOutbound = new OnewayAdapter(rv.getContext(), list);
    rvResultOutbound.setAdapter(adapterOutbound);
    rvResultOutbound.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(rv.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    return rv;
}
public OutboundFragment(ArrayList<ListItem> list, int position) {
    this.list = list;
    this.position = position;
}
```

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: add complete activity and fragment and add logcat also

Comment: This activity is too long, so I don't show it here. All of steps before sendResultRoundtripDomestic() function are ok but when add fragment to activity, the data aren't show :(((((((. The fragment is a custom view of tablayout in parent activity.